# Redirecting IE 7 or lower users

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, redirect

I have this 100% javascript/html/css based application.  We will functionality support IE8 and display an upgrade message at the top using the ie6nomore method.

The issue I am running into is blocking everyone using IE and on version 7 or lower from accessing the page.  I am running apache so I though maybe I could just do a mod rewrite so that all IE users on version 7 a lower are redirected to a force upgrade notice page.

How would I accomplish this which Apache mod-rewrite?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: +1 for kicking old IE versions, wish my customer would let me do the same...

Answer (score 0):

While I realize this is Perl, you should be able to use this regular expression in your preferred language:

```
if ($ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'} =~ /MSIE [67]/)
{
  blah
}
```

It isn't foolproof, of course, but when you're planning on trusting the client, nothing will be.